# Firestore:delete cloud function failing

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-tools

I'm trying to use cloud functions to delete users from Firestore from a Flutter app. I have a callable function to delete the user from firebase.auth which works fine.

The onDelete() function triggers as it should but then fails.

```
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";
const firebase_tools = require('firebase-tools');


exports.deleteUserDocs = functions.auth.user().onDelete((user) => {
    const userID = user.uid;
    const path = `/users/${userID}`;

    console.log(`User ${userID} has requested to delete path ${path}`);

    return firebase_tools.firestore
        .delete(path, {
            project: 764017482510,
            recursive: true,
            token: functions.config().fb.token,
            yes: true,
        })
        .then(() => {
            console.log(`User data with ${userID} was deleted`);
            return { "status": "Success" };
        })

});
```

This is the error message I get:

```
FirebaseError: Deletion failed. Errors: Failed to fetch documents to delete >= 3 times..
    at Timeout.<anonymous> (/workspace/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/firestore/delete.js:272:32)
    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:554:17)
    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:497:7)
```

If I run `firebase firestore:delete` from the terminal using the same path, the document is deleted without any issues.

Any ideas would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are you using as for the project field? I believe you should be using your Firebase project id.

```
{
  project: "firebase_project_id",
  recursive: true,
  token: functions.config().fb.token,
  yes: true,
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to answer! I can't believe I didn't check that. I was using the project number as `process.env.GCP_PROJECT` never worked for me. All working now!